Name resolution fails in Logic App for API Management service in private virtual network
Trying to move a set of logic apps into an azure private virtual network, with a single API manager to manage all calls to external platforms. Got all that set up, and I can now make a call to the API Management Service, and if I make a call to an endpoint via its IP address (10.2.1.4) it works perfectly, I even set up a virtual machine in the same subnet and using postman I can prove it all works.
The problem is that if I then try to add the API Manager in a Logic App, it finds the API, I can select any of the Operation id, and it lists all the Advanced Parameters, all good, but when I try to run it, it fails with a:

Http request failed with status code 'HostNotFound' and status message: 'No such host is known.'.

So the reason is (probably) quite straight forward, it can't hind the hostname for the API Manager, my problem is, is there a way to tell the logic app that, when you try to call:
https://myamazingAPIManager.azure-api.net
Use the IP 10.2.1.4
Or am I missing something completely?

OK, after a lot of faffing about, I've come to the conclusion that they JUST do not want the API Manager inside the virtual network. I think you could get around it by setting up a DNS inside the VNET, then force the traffic to the API Manager to use the internal IP. But you can't use another address for it (because the API Manager demands that you use it's full URL, including azure-api.com)
So what you need to do is:
Move the API out of the private or external Vnet

Add a private endpoint to the API Manager

After that, it works nicely, however, if you were planning to use the vnet to secure your apps, you now need to lock down the API Manager separately, we will probably just block it from accepting any requests not from the endpoint, but that is for later.
